# Change filename of File

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have code to get file from `clipboard` and need to change it's name if it's name `image.png`

Here is my code, where I try to do this:

```
  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
    const items: DataTransferItem[] = Array.from(clipboardData.items);
    let copiedFiles: File[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      let file = items[i].getAsFile();
      if (file.name.includes('image')) {
        file.name = this.getScreenshotFilename();
      } else {
      }
      copiedFiles.push(items[i].getAsFile());
    }

    this.files = this.concat(copiedFiles);
  }

    private getScreenshotFilename(): string {
    return `Screenshot_${formatDate(new Date(), 'yymmddHHMMss', DATE_LOCALE)}`;
  }
```

But at this line  `file.name = this.getScreenshotFilename();` , I get the following error :

> Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property.

How I can edit name of file?

Comment: You can create a new file and copy the properties.

Comment: @jabaa How I can do this?

Comment: _"How I can do this?"_ [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Read the documentation: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) _"The `File()` constructor creates a new `File` object instance. "_

Answer (score 1):

[MDN File()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

`new File([oldFile], 'image.png', { type: oldFile.type })`

```
  // ...

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
    const items: DataTransferItem[] = Array.from(clipboardData.items);
    let copiedFiles: File[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      let file = items[i].getAsFile();
      let newFile;

      if (file.name.includes('image')) {
        newFile = new File([file], this.getScreenshotFilename(), { type: file.type })
        
        copiedFiles.push(newFile);
      } else {
        // exception handling
      }
    }

    this.files = this.concat(copiedFiles);
  }

  private getScreenshotFilename(): string {
  return `Screenshot_${formatDate(new Date(), 'yymmddHHMMss', DATE_LOCALE)}`;
}
```

Comment: I think this code is not correct. The OP copies the all files into `copiedFiles`.